# Autoplay an embeded youtube livestream

Tags: javascript, html

There are many answers on how to autoplay a regular youtube video but this doesn't work for a livestream.  I've also tried autoclicking the embedded link using something like

```
<script>
var els = document.querySelectorAll(".ytp-large-play-button ytp-button")
[].forEach.call(els, function (el) {el.click()});
</script>
```

but the class selector returns undefined. fyi "ytp-large-play-button ytp-button" is what I see as the class for the button when I inspect using chrome.

As per the comment below, adding ?autoplay=true makes the embedded livestream autoplay

Comment: Can we see your embed code? `?autoplay=true` seems to work for me.

Comment: This does in fact work for livestreams

Answer (score 0):

this also works for embedded livestreams

```
?autoplay=true
```

just delete the

```
?controls=0&amp;showinfo=0
```

from the embedded code provided by youtube